# Method called by another method running in thread will run in that thread also?

Tags: android, multithreading

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getLinks();
            }
        });
    }
}

     private void getLinks(){
       String link;
        // my work
       Download(link);
     }
    
    private void Download(String Link){
        // my work
    }
```

Will the other method also run in that thread, as we called getlinks() then getlinks() called the Download() method, will the downloading will run in the background or I have to stay my activity open, in my android app.

Comment: Don't say "...method running in thread..." A method doesn't _do_ anything. It doesn't do anything in precisely the same way that a recipe does not make your dinner. A _cook_ makes the dinner by executing the instructions in the recipe, and a _thread_ does `// my work` by executing the instructions in your methods. So, when a thread is executing your `getLinks()` method, and it gets to the line that says, call `Download(link)`, what's the thread going to do...?

Comment: ok I will try this, that suits my task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fact:** When we are using IntelliJ IDE and we all know that there is a method named as `public static void main(String ars[]){ }` remember? So this is a method and all the code that runs in this method will run in the main thread.

**Answer -** So if we call a method from a thread then each line of code in that method, will run in that thread.

**Example :** So the thread is a car and anything that is called by this car will travel in that car , even if a person is called by a person who is already traveling in that car will have to travel in that car. Each person need a car to travel. Each method needs a thread to run.

**Extra Fact -** You know in android, there is a thread called UI thread, so whenever you want to make changes to UI then u have to use that thread or it will crash the app.

I recommend you this udemy course [ by Michael Pogrebinsky ] to understand multithreading in java. [Java Multithreading, Concurrency & Performance Optimization](https://www.udemy.com/course/java-multithreading-concurrency-performance-optimization/)